# The joined is located outside of the base path component

Tags: python, django, media

**Good Morning Everyone,**
I developed an app in Django (latest version). On local server it is working well. But for **deployment when I run command for collect static then the error occurred**

```
The joined path (C:\Users\Galaxy\PycharmProjects\plugins\js_composer\assets\images\icons\address-book.png) is located
 outside of the base path component (C:\Users\Galaxy\PycharmProjects\medical_store\staticfiles).
```

**I'm using HTML and Bootstrap for front-end but this path error occurred.
It's my terminal showing**

```
  return safe_join(self.location, name)
  File "C:\Users\Galaxy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 29, in safe_join
    raise SuspiciousFileOperation(
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (C:\Users\Galaxy\PycharmProjects\plugins\js_composer\assets\images\icons\address-book.png) is located
 outside of the base path component (C:\Users\Galaxy\PycharmProjects\medical_store\staticfiles)
```

**I tried to replace the url that was first looking as**

```
{background-image:url(../../../plugins/js_composer/assets/images/icons/address-book.png)}
```

**then I replace it by**

```
{background-image:url(../../../medical_store/static/img/address-book.png)}
```

But same error found.
**I don't know how to remove this error. Have you any idea what I have to do exactly?**

**Here is my settings for staticfiles.**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```